# HammerJS triggers click after dragend

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch, hammer.js

I have a perfectly working hammerjs drag listener that captures drags just like I'd expect. But when you let go, right after the dragend is `triggered`, it then triggers a `click` event as well. So if you were clicking to drag (move) the target, and the cursor happened to be over a link, when you let go (drop), it triggers a click on the link, which I don't want.

Here's my code:

```
$('.draggable').hammer({
    drag_min_distance: 0,
    drag_max_touches: 2,
    drag_lock_to_axis: true,
    drag_lock_min_distance: 30
}).on('drag', handleMiddleEvent)
  .on('dragstart', handleStartEvent)
  .on('dragend', handleEndEvent);
```

If I console.log the `event` on all three handlers *and* console.log click `events` on all links, I get something like this in my console:

```
dragstart
dragmiddle
dragmiddle
dragmiddle
dragmiddle
dragend
click
```

I want to avoid the click at the end. I tried adding `event.stopPropagation()` to all of the handle methods, but to no avail.

Comment: I was able to hack a solution by adding a "is_dragging" global var, setting it to true in handleStartEvent, and putting a 100ms setTimeout in handleEndEvent that sets it to false, and then checking the global var on my click handlers. But that is so ugly.. I'm really hoping for something better.

Comment: Did you find a better solution?

Answer (score 3):

Try using Hammer.js `tap` events instead of the `click` events on the links.

Comment: It's a bit messy preventing clicks and binding taps instead but it works.

Answer (score -1):

I had a pretty similar problem, and found some kind of workaround - I know it's dirty but the links are not being clicked by a drag. I want to drag a wrapper-div, which is my wrapper element seen in the js below. It has several links in it, wich are being clicked when the dragging stops above them, and i want to prevent that from happening.

First, i define a div that is on top of everything but set hidden in my html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <div id="linklist">
          <-- Links etc in here-->
          <div id="preventClick" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; width: 5000px; height: 6000px; "></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Then, in the hammer functions, the div is set to visible at a dragstart (in this case, a dragdown) - you just can't see it because it has no background-color or any content.
JS:

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");

Hammer(wrapper).on("dragdown", function() {
     handleDragDown();  //call function that handles movement
     var preventClick = document.getElementById("preventClick");
     preventClick.style.visibility = 'visible';
});

Hammer(wrapper).on("dragend", function() {
     var preventClick = document.getElementById("preventClick");
     preventClick.style.visibility = 'hidden';
});
```

I know this is far from perfect and your post is from several months ago, but it worked for me. Hope i could help :)